# Test django pagination ordering on ListView with large page size

Tags: django, testing

I have a view with a fixed pagination size of 100.  I need to test that the ordering is correct, given the pagination.

Looking at [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Testing#views) I can create 100 + 1 objects, then test that the expected objects are returned, but this takes a very long time (1 minute+).

Is there a way to reduce the pagination size on a `generic.ListView` for tests?  I essentially want to test that the get_queryset method is returning the correct results.

Here is my slow running test so far:

```py
def test_custom_ordering():
    """
    test that page ordering is correct, and works with pagination
    standard page size is 100
    NOTE populating 100 results takes a long time, thus we run all ordering tests in this method
    """
    feedbacks = []
    # create 101 feedbacks on consecutive days
    for i in range(0, 102):
        feedbacks.append(
            factory.create_feedback(
                date=datetime(2021, 1, 1) + timedelta(days=i),
            )
        )

    # no ordering specified => default: requested_at
    response = requests.get(f'{URL_NAME}?order_by=date')
    results = response.html.findChildren("table")[0].findChildren("tr")

    # expect feedback 0 (oldest) up to 101 (100 page size)
    # first of results is header, so ignore
    utils.check_same_results(feedbacks[:100], results[1:])
```

Comment: I suggestion to optimize your code is to use list comprehension plus bulk_create to create factory objects that would increase speed.

Comment: @Ahtisham thanks for that, i'll have a look at bulk_create